# Error handling with react-router

Tags: react-router

I am struggling a little bit to find a good method for error handling with clientside routing with react-router.

Say I transition from one page to another, and an error occurs when attempting to fetch data (using redial), or something errors while trying to render the components for my page. It doesn't seem like these errors hit the onError function I pass to my Router...

I wasn't able to find much information looking around github issues. Does anyone have a good pattern they like for rendering an error page whenever something unexpected happens on clientside transitions?

Comment: See https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/538